# Spring Kafka - missing information about __TypeId__ in the consumer headers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm exploring Spring Kafka API (`spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.7.4`) and I found strange behavior in the consumer with standard `@KafkaListener` annotation.

I produce messages with `KafkaTemplate` and add custom header prop `__ProducerApp__`, but I have standard header prop `__TypeId__` too because it is automatically added by Spring starter implementation.

Properties:

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    consumer:
      group-id: consumer-localhost
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      properties.spring.json.trusted.packages: '*'
```

Producer class:

```java
@Component
public class KafkaExampleProducer {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaPayload> kafkaTemplate;

    public KafkaExampleProducer(KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaPayload> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    public void sendPayload(KafkaPayload payload) {
        ProducerRecord<String, KafkaPayload> record = new ProducerRecord<>(
                KafkaExampleTopicConfig.EXAMPLE_TOPIC_NAME, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), payload
        );
        record.headers().add("__ProducerApp__", "ExampleApp-localhost".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        kafkaTemplate.send(record);
    }
}
```

I can see fulfilled headers in the [web UI for Apache Kafka](https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui):
[image: kafka message headers]

But in the consumer, after receiving a message from a topic I see only the `__ProducerApp__` header prop.

Listener class:

```java
@Component
public class KafkaExampleListener {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaExampleListener.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = KafkaExampleTopicConfig.EXAMPLE_TOPIC_NAME)
    public void listenMessage(
            ConsumerRecord<String, KafkaPayload> consumerRecord
    ) {
        logger.info("Received message:\nKey: {}, type: {}, producer: {}",
                consumerRecord.key(),
                extractHeaderValue(consumerRecord.headers(), "__TypeId__"),
                extractHeaderValue(consumerRecord.headers(), "__ProducerApp__")
        );
    }

    private String extractHeaderValue(Headers headers, String headerId) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(headers.spliterator(), false)
                .filter(header -> header.key().equals(headerId))
                .findFirst()
                .map(header -> new String(header.value()))
                .orElse("N/A");
    }
}
```

The console result presents that headers are received without `__TypeId__` prop:

```
Received message:
Key: 3e8ee64e-b691-48e1-98b1-614291cc0451, type: N/A, producer: ExampleApp-localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not add your beans configs, but my guess is that you are missing the correct deserializer props.

Add:

```
@Bean 
RecordMessageConverter messageConverter() {  return new 
StringJsonMessageConverter();  }
```

Also, instead of a `JsonDeserializer` use a `StringDeserializer` in your consumer  `value-deserializer`

Comment: But how deserializer can make effort to headers? When I changed `JsonDeserializer` into the `StringDeserializer` I have information about `__TypeId__` but... why my custom headers (like `__ProducerApp__`) worked before? I lost auto deserialization functionality too (I have to change the consumer signature to `<String, String>` and deserialize the message step by step).

Answer (score 1):

The `JsonDeserializer` strips the type headers by default to avoid polluting the application with internals.

```
/**
 * Set to false to retain type information headers after deserialization.
 * Default true.
 * @param removeTypeHeaders true to remove headers.
 * @since 2.2
 */
public void setRemoveTypeHeaders(boolean removeTypeHeaders) {
    this.removeTypeHeaders = removeTypeHeaders;
    this.setterCalled = true;
}
```

Or set `spring.json.remove.type.headers: false`.